# Error while generating entity with composite primary key

Tags: php, sql, symfony, doctrine

I realized today I was missing one of my entities. I generated the XML metadata and then generated the entity. I tried regenerate the entity, but still I haven't managed to regenerate it successfully.

That entity has composite primary key. And each part of that key is actually foregin key.

**SQL:**

```
CREATE TABLE lajki (
    _wydarzenie_id INT NOT NULL,
    _uzytkownik_id INT NOT NULL,
    _lajk_data DATETIME NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (_wydarzenie_id, _uzytkownik_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (_uzytkownik_id) REFERENCES uzytkownicy(_uzytkownik_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (_wydarzenie_id) REFERENCES wydarzenia(_wydarzenie_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

XML metadata:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<doctrine-mapping xmlns="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping" 
                  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
                  xsi:schemaLocation="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping.xsd">
  <entity name="Lajki" table="lajki">
    <change-tracking-policy>DEFERRED_IMPLICIT</change-tracking-policy>
    <id name="wydarzenieId" type="integer" column="_wydarzenie_id"/>
    <id name="uzytkownikId" type="integer" column="_uzytkownik_id"/>
    <field name="lajkData" type="datetime" column="_lajk_data"/>
    <lifecycle-callbacks/>
  </entity>
</doctrine-mapping>
```

What I have to do to have it working? Do I have write entity by myself or I have just to change something?

Comment: What do you mean by "but still I haven't managed to regenerate it successfully"? How do you "regenerate entity"?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are talking about the [command line tool](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/reference/tools.html) which generates classes and proxies from annotations. Generally the tool is not very good. It has a lot of problems with inheritance, and it seems, with composite (**not dual**) keys in your case.

Try to correct the annotations in your entity classes manually, don't use the tool. If you want to use it so badly, generate everything only the first time, correct the errors tool can't resolve, and forget about that tool ever existed :)

Btw. although Doctrine supports composite keys, their usage is discouraged. So don't use them if they are not really necessary. See the [documentation](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/reference/best-practices.html#avoid-composite-keys).